# Problem when changing context (impersonation) and using a server link in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, impersonation, database-link

I get a strange behaviour when I combine impersonation with database links in SQL Server 2005. First, I connect to a database server using simple SQL Server Authentication with Login *'John'*. On this server, a server link **remote_sqlserver** is defined. I already have SELECT privileges for **mydb** in this server. When I simply query a table on a DB on this server link:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM remote_sqlserver.mydb.dbo.mytable  -- Works!
```

After that, I try impersonation with the same Login (don't ask why would one do that, I'm just experimenting ;) )

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'John'

SELECT count(*)
FROM remote_sqlserver.mydb.dbo.mytable  -- Error: "Login failed for user: 'John'"
```

When I revert, it works again:

```
REVERT

SELECT count(*)
FROM remote_sqlserver.mydb.dbo.mytable  -- Works!
```

Do you have any idea, why I get an error with impersonation, although the same *Login* can query the table without impersonation?

BTW: After "impersonation as self", if I query a local database, (of course, for which I have enough privileges) I don't get any error. It only happens when I query a remote DB via server link.

Comment: It might be the default database for that user that's not right? I'm not sure, so not a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Could you make it clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the Books Online article "Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS".

When you use EXECUTE AS to access a remote server, the remote server has to be configured to trust the caller.  Even though the the "parent" and "child" logins are the same (i.e. "John") since you are using EXECUTE AS the trust relationships have to be set up.  The authentication "path" is different even though the login is the same.

Comment: Also a recommended reading: http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#execas-crossdb 
The keyword is "TRUSTWORTHY"

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be interesting if authentication would work by simple means of trusting who you say you are? One would say "I'm John, give me all the money in my account" and the bank would pay up the cash. Now, fortunately, the authentication systems used everywhere will be just a tad more demanding and when one shows up and say "I'm John", he will be challenged "Hullo John, so... what is your password?".

Exactly the same thing goes on here. You may notice that when you say `EXECUTE AS Login = 'John'` you *did not provide a password*. So the SQL Server instance may have been 'fooled' that you're "John", but nobody outside SQL will believe you (and the "fooling" inside SQL is a long story of trust and privileges in fact, what really happens is more like "I am the SYSADMIN and I SAY that thou shall believe this user is John!".

If you want to access anything outside the SQL Server system and **be** John, then you need to specify John's password. The usual way is by using a credential object, with [`CREATE CREDENTIAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189522.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the easy explanation. I will read more about that. However, in this particular case, I AM already connected to server as John, before I say "hello server, I just wanted to tell you again: I AM John". That's why I thought it shouldn't cause much trouble if I say "I am John" again and again...

Comment: The moment you said EXECUTE AS your previous credentials are no longer relevant.

Comment: But when I query another *local* database after I say EXECUTE AS, I don't get an error (see the BTW note under the question.) If what you say is true, I shouldn't be able to do that as well, right?

Comment: Another *local* database trusts the sysadmin who vouched for you, so its all good. If you would had said EXECUTE AS **USER** = 'John' then your 'idenity' would havd been vouched for by dbo, not sysadmin, and the whole 'extending database impersonation context' discussion would apply. But since you said EXECUTE AS **LOGIN** = 'John', your identity is good anywhere in the local SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, it might be worth having a quick read up on [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) and [Ownership Chains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) in case they can shed any light on the problems you're having